# Unavailable property with a property wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on an app that supports iOS 14 and up, but I would like to use some of the SwiftUI 3 property wrappers like `@FocusState`.

How can I work around the `Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable` error?

Here is the simplified version of our code, it works with Xcode 13, but fails to compile with Xcode 14.

```
struct MyView: View {
  enum Field: Hashable {
    case username
  }

  @State private var myText: String = ""

  @available(iOS 15, *)
  @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

  var body: some View {
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
      TextEditor(text: $myText)
        .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
    } else {
      TextEditor(text: $myText)
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot use a [computed property with a backing storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43503888/1672972) workaround as a computed property cannot have a property wrapper.

Are there any other workarounds that I can use except for an almost identical copy of `MyView`?

Comment: You either need to implement `MyView` twice - Once for iOS14+ and once for earlier versions, drop the use of `@FocusState` or drop iOS13 support.  Personally, that is what I would do.  A device that is stuck on ios13 is 8+ years old.

Comment: Hm, thanks @Paulw11, `@FocusState` is only iOS 15+ and we have about 10% of our customer base still on iOS 14, so not ready to drop support for that. I'm leaning towards writing `MyView` twice at this stage, but maybe somebody could think of a nicer workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible approach is to separate all dependent parts into one subview, and mark it as available for new OS.

Here is a demo:

```
struct MyView: View {
    enum Field: Hashable {
        case username
    }

    @State private var myText: String = ""

    @available(iOS 15, *)            // << here !!
    struct NewTextEditor: View {
        @Binding var text: String
        @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?

        var body: some View {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
        }
    }


    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            NewTextEditor(text: $myText)
        } else {
            TextEditor(text: $myText)
        }
    }
}
```