# How to use `.backgroundTask` modifier while still targeting iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, background-task, ios16

I'm trying to use the new [.backgroundTask modifier](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10142/) announced at WWDC '22 but I can't get the below to compile? Xcode says `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'appRefresh'`  How can I do this?

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import BackgroundTasks

  var body: some Scene {
      WindowGroup {
          if #available(iOS 16, *) {
              AppRootView()
                  .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("refreshAllData")) {
                      refreshData() 
                  }
          } else {
              AppRootView()
          }
      }
  }
```

Edit: as agentBilly said .backgroundTask is a scene modifier, so should look like this but I'm still unsure how to check for iOS 16 availability?

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import BackgroundTasks


@main
struct myApp: App {
    
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
   
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppRootView()
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("refreshAllData")) {
            refreshAllData() 
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to put everything new into separated view and use compiler-time `@available` modifier and `#if canImport`. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/72933630/12299030.

Comment: The new `.backgroundTask(_:action:)` seems to be a scene modifier, could you provide more details on `AppRootView`?

Comment: @AgentBilly you are correct, see my edited Question.

Comment: @Asperi see my edit, how to check availability like in that question but for a `Scene`?

Comment: @GarySabo check out [this](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/conditional-view-modifier/), you can put the availability check in a custom conditional modifier. btw, did it solve your original issue with the implicit member chaining?

Comment: @AgentBilly thanks I actually have used this before for a `View` but this doesn't work for a `Scene` and simply changing out `Scene` for `View` in the custom conditional modifier doesn't work.  

Comment: Yeah sorry haha I just realized that it only works with Views since scenes don't have a `@SceneModifier`, I'm afraid you'd have to go for the dirty solution, which is introducing an if-else branch in your `body` (don't know if that works, maybe you can try it out).

Comment: @Asperi your solution worked in a test app but implementing it in my actual production app failed for `error build: Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code` and that's all it gives me so I'm not really sure why.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot use condition right in scene body, because `SceneBuilder` does not support conditional expression, so a solution is to have completely different apps loaded depending on availability.

Simplified code to have less lines:

```
struct AppScene: Scene {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16, *)
struct RefreshingAppScene: Scene {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("refreshAllData")) {
            refreshAllData()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct AppLoader {
    static func main() {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {  // << conditional availability !!
            New_iOSApp.main()
        } else {
            Old_iOSApp.main()
        }
    }
}

@available (iOS 16, *)
struct New_iOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        RefreshingAppScene()
    }
}

struct Old_iOSApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        AppScene()
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 14b3 / iOS 16

Comment: This solution crashes my app on iOS 14 for some reason. I'm not sure why. Someone who got the same issue and a solution?