# Xcode 14 beta error: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios16, xcode14

I get this error when I run my app on Xcode 14 beta and I don't know how to fix it:

> Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'

It doesn't pop up when I run Xcode 13, and the app runs smoothly. I am in the .xcworkspace file.

Comment: If the problem is in RevenueCat it isn't your code so there's nothing you can do. File a bug with the code authors and go back to Xcode 13.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797366/stored-properties-cannot-be-marked-potentially-unavailable-with-available

Comment: I faced same issue, any one have solution pls share

Comment: I've fixed it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904724/using-available-with-stored-properties/73699790#73699790

Answer (score 24):

I have this error in Flutter project in XCode 14. One of the external packages were using:

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
My current fix is:

Update version in Podfile platform :ios, '14.0',
pod update &&
Pod install

Comment: Is there a way to solving it not defining the iOS 14 as a global platform?

Comment: In my code happened this issue was resolved like what i mentioned above. please mention your exact issue. This issue only happened when i was updating the latest Xcode version. @jed1

Answer (score 17):

Let me tell you **100% working solution** if this error is being raised due to `DKImagePickerController`.

Follow these steps:

1. Goto your Podfile and replace this **https://github.com/miguelpruivo/DKImagePickerController.git** url with this **https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController.git** url.
2. In your flutter project run following commands:
   2.1) `flutter clean`
   2.2) `flutter pub get`
3. Navigate to ios folder and run following commands:
   3.1) `pod install` (use `arch -x86_64 pod install` if you are using M1)
   3.2) `pod update` (use `arch -x86_64 pod update` if you are using M1)
4. Run your project.

Comment: True story! This is the best solution for this project.
This has happened due to some project discontinuation as I can remember.

Thanks for documenting.

Comment: For step3 got this error `arch: posix_spawnp: pod: Bad CPU type in executable`

Comment: can u specify guide replace the git url ? i didnt find the text / url

Answer (score 16):

In Xcode 13, and lower, you were able to compile if you used a lazy @available stored property as such:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
private(set) lazy var center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
```

However, this does not work in Xcode 14.

Instead, you need to use a non-available stored property, *and* use a **computed** @available property:

```
private var _selectionFeedbackGenerator: Any? = nil
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
fileprivate var selectionFeedbackGenerator: UISelectionFeedbackGenerator {
    if _selectionFeedbackGenerator == nil {
        _selectionFeedbackGenerator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
    }
    return _selectionFeedbackGenerator as! UISelectionFeedbackGenerator
}
```

[Answer source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43503888/826435)

Answer (score 14):

In my case the problem was in `flutter_inappwebview` package. I've fixed it by using the newest version - 5.4.4+3

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/install

Comment: this worked for me, I had `flutter_inappwebview` version 5.3.2, changed it to 5.4.4, `flutter pub get`, and it's working, thank you!

Comment: How did you use the newest version, what did you do?

Comment: How can I install this package?

Comment: There is no such a library in my pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to change both sections of the iOS Deployment Target in the Build Settings tab, like in my picture:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. As directed by the repository on GitHub, a workaround is to update the Podfile version: `platform :ios, '14.0'`

Answer (score 1):

In My case, I changed 'available' statements like below.

// the code occurs error on xcode 15 (swift 5.9)

```
@available(swift, obsoleted: 0.6.3, renamed: "changeCallback")
public var changeFunction: ChangeFunction? = nil
```

// the code vailed on xcode 15 (swift 5.9)

```
@available(*, unavailable, renamed: "changeCallback")
public var changeFunction: ChangeFunction? {
    set {
        changeCallback = newValue
    }
    get {
        return changeCallback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, I just find a solution for my project, It may comes to you workaround, but I still would like to share my experience about it;

```
class MyClass {
    @available(iOS 15.0, *) // Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'
    var myProperty: String
}
```

Xcode offers us entire class to make @available

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
class MyClass {
    var myProperty: String
}
```

This is my workaround solution. You can use the @available attribute on its getter and setter methods instead of the property itself.

```
class MyClass {
    private var myValue: String = ""
    
    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    var myProperty: String {
        get {
            return myValue
        }
        set {
            myValue = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

This is from my real project;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My case:

1. Remove ios folder. (Should save your Info.plist)
2. flutter create .
3. Change ios to 14. (Pod file)
4. flutter pub get => cd ios => pod install => cd .. => flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Do update your latest verison replaced with obsoleted
@available(swift, obsoleted: 5.0, renamed: "unitTitle")

after update looks like - @available(swift, obsoleted: 15.0, renamed: "unitTitle")
that resolve my problem